# How I can use operator OR in CouchDB?

Tags: node.js, couchdb, couchdb-futon

I need get doc where createdBy=userId or updatedBy= userId.
I have next map func in CouchDB:

```
function (doc) {
                        if (doc.$doctype === 'Records') {
                            emit([doc.createdBy, doc.updatedBy], doc);
                        }
                    }
```

And node.js backend

```
getData: async (userId) => {
        return await adapter.getRows(
            'Records', 'url',
            {
                startkey: [userId, userId],
                endkey: [userId],
            }
        );
    }
```

but it works as operator AND. Please help me find mistake.

Comment: Why use array key? emit(doc.createdBy, null); emit(doc.updatedBy, null) in view will allow you to request with keys:[userId1, userId2, ...] to get union (however probably with dupes).

Comment: Since CouchDB 2.x, you can use OR with a [mango query](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/api/database/find.html). See the [combination operators](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/api/database/find.html#combination-operators).

Comment: @Flimzy please tell me, how I can combine mango query and view or I need change request in node ? I create mango query in Fauxton  - it is works, but I don't understand how use it with view and node.js ...

Comment: You don't combine them. You'd need to change to a mango query.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you can't do a OR from a single request yet.

*(As of CouchDB 2.1, the [_queries](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/pull/1222) endpoint is not yet available. In the future, you will be able to request multiple queries in the same HTTP request).*

Using startkey and endkey syntax, OR would be the equivalent of:

**createdBy**

- startKey=[john]
- endkey=[john,{}]

**updatedBy**

- startKey=[null,john]
- endkey=[{},john]

Then, you could do an union of the two result sets.

If you're using CouchDB 2.X, you should use Mango selector with the **$or** operator.

## Other solution

You could create a specific view for this request.

For example, you would index both the updatedBy and createdBy.

```
if (doc.$doctype === 'Records') {
   emit([doc.createdBy, doc.createdAt]);
   emit([doc.updatedBy, doc.createdAt]);
}
```

Then, you can query it with `startkey=[author]&endkey=[author,{}]`

Comment: I use CouchDB 1.6.1 and I try next func:  
`emit([doc.updatedBy, doc.createdAt] || [doc.createdBy, doc.createdAt], doc);` and it works... How about it ?

Comment: Hum, I don't see how it works. [a,b] || [c,d] gives [a,b]. So basically, it only index  [doc.updatedBy, doc.createdAt]

Comment: You just made me realized another solution(I updated my answer). Also, don't ever index the doc. It put extra data in the index that is already available with the ?include_docs=true parameter

Comment: Sorry for delay and thanks for answer but I decide moved from couchDB from 1.6 to 2.1. Also if I will be use `emit([doc.createdBy, doc.createdAt]);
   emit([doc.updatedBy, doc.createdAt]);`
I get duplicate records.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
function (doc) {
   if (doc.$doctype === 'Records') {
       emit(doc.createdBy, "created");
       emit(doc.updatedBy, "updated");
   }
}
```

then you can query using a single key of the userID, the value is extra info on the action if that is needed, otherwise you can just leave it nil.

Do not emit a value of doc because that is redundant, you can always get the doc using

> include_docs

query options.